# When can we say that $E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \geq 0$ for a real-valued random variable $X$?

Tags: probability, proof-writing, expectation, positive-semidefinite

This a related but separate question to: [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2580093/x-a-random-variable-if-eb-i-x2-lt-infty-for-basis-b-i-of-v-c).

I'm trying to prove that the matrix derived, $\Sigma$ is non-negative definite, and I think knowing the question in the title will help.

Background: some lebesgue integration, but not pro at it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance

Comment: The expression is equal to $E[(X-E(X))^2]$. Squares are always non-negative. Expectation of a non-negative RV is again non-negative. This is why the variance of an RV can never be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could observe that $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2$, and that the variance is always nonnegative.  However, since it isn't that hard to show, it might be nice to see *why* that is.

Recall that
$$ \operatorname{Var}(X) := E([X-E(X)]^2) = \int_{\Omega} (X-E(X))^2 \,\mathrm{d}P(x),$$
where $\Omega$ is the sample space and $P$ is the probability measure associated to the random variable $X$.  Since $P$ is a nonnegative measure and $(x - E(X))^2 \ge 0$ for all $x\in \Omega$, it follows that
$$ \operatorname{Var}(X) \ge 0.  \tag{1}$$
We can then exploit the linearity of the integral (i.e. the linearity of expectation) in order to obtain
\begin{align}
E([X-E(X)]^2)
&= E(X^2 - 2XE(X) + E(X)^2) \\
&= E(X^2) - 2E(X)^2 + E(X)^2 \\
&= E(X^2) - E(X)^2. \tag{2} \end{align}
Combining (1) and (2), we get the desired result, namely
$$ 0 \le \operatorname{Var}(X) = E([X-E(X)]^2) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2. $$
In point of fact, we really only need the second computation, as $E([X-E(X)]^2)$ is the expectation of a nonnegative random variable, and a nonnegative random variable must have nonnegative expectation.  However, the connection to the variance is worth emphasizing (I can't tell you how sad it makes me when I have to mark down exam questions because students compute negative values for the variance, then give me imaginary standard deviations).

Comment: Any advice on my linked post?  See my answer it's still unresolved

Answer (score 2):

The variance of a real random variable $X$ is given as
$$V(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$$
Since $V(X)\geq 0$ always...

Answer (score 1):

Define the constant  $\mu = E[X]$ and random variable $\Delta = X - \mu$, so $X = \mu + 
\Delta$.

$E[\Delta] = E [X - \mu] = E[X] - \mu = \mu - \mu = 0$.

Remember when $s$ is constant, that $E[A + B] = E[A] + E[B]$, $E[sA] = sE[A]$, and $E[s]=s$
$$\begin{align}
E[X^2] - E[X]^2 & = E[(\mu + \Delta)^2] - E[\mu + \Delta]^2\\
& = E[\mu^2 + 2\mu\Delta + \Delta^2] - (E[\mu] + E[\Delta])^2\\
& = E[\mu^2] + E[2 \mu \Delta] + E[\Delta^2] - (E[\mu] + 0)^2\\
& = \mu^2 + 2 \mu E[\Delta] + E[\Delta^2] - (\mu)^2\\
&= 2 \mu 0 + E[\Delta^2]\\
&  = E[\Delta^2] \ge 0\\
\end{align}$$